# How to make props button link clickable?

Tags: react-router

I have a React card component as in the code below:

```js
import React from "react";

class Cardlist extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return(
        <div className="cardlist">
        <div className="cardlist-body">
        <h2>{this.props.title}</h2><br/>
        <p>{this.props.text}</p><br/><br/>
        <button className="button-49">{this.props.btnlink}</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  export default Cardlist;
  
  
  
  
import React from "react";
import Cardlist from "./Cardlist";

const Services = () => {
    return(<section id="services">
    <div class="servicesContainer">
    
    <div class="servicesContent">
    <Cardlist title="Pain Management" text="We offer patients the very best pain medications and treatments. We advise our patients to seek treatment for their chronic pain and learn that management is possible with the right tools [...]" btnlink ="Read More"/>
       
    </div>
    
    <div class="servicesContent">
    <Cardlist title="Dermatology" text="The compounding pharmacist prepares therapies customized for the individual patient for a very wide range of dermatological conditions. Such skin conditions can spell not only physical di [...]" btnlink ="Read More"/>
    </div>

    <div class="servicesContent">
    <Cardlist title="Pediatric" text="Children and medications often times just do not mix. Children often resist taking a medication because they don’t like the taste. Swallowing pills is often difficult for younger children [...]" btnlink ="Read More"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="servicesContent">
    <Cardlist title="Hormone Replacement Therapy" text="Children and medications often times just do not mix. Children often resist taking a medication because they don’t like the taste. Swallowing pills is often difficult for younger children [...]" btnlink ="Read More" />
    </div>
</div>
</section>);
}

export default Services;
```

Clearly, as you can see I can't pass a link to btnlink ="Read More". When is the best and easiest way to assign every button its own LINK (external or internal link)?

You can see the design on live website: http://fusionrxny.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a onClick listener on your button element

```js
import React from "react";

class Cardlist extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    // this will open your link in new tab
    window.open(this.props.linkUrl, '_blank');
  }
    render() {
      return(
        <div className="cardlist">
        <div className="cardlist-body">
        <h2>{this.props.title}</h2><br/>
        <p>{this.props.text}</p><br/><br/>
        <button className="button-49" onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.btnlink}</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  export default Cardlist;
```

or you can replace your button element with a link element

```js
import React from "react";

class Cardlist extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return(
        <div className="cardlist">
        <div className="cardlist-body">
        <h2>{this.props.title}</h2><br/>
        <p>{this.props.text}</p><br/><br/>
        <a className="button-49" href={this.props.linkUrl}>{this.props.btnlink}</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  export default Cardlist;
```

you would provide different urls like this

```js
import React from "react";
import Cardlist from "./Cardlist";

const Services = () => {
    return(<section id="services">
    <div class="servicesContainer">
    
    <div class="servicesContent">
    <Cardlist 
      title="Pain Management" 
      text="We offer patients the very best pain medications and treatments. We advise our patients to seek treatment for their chronic pain and learn that management is possible with the right tools [...]" 
      btnlink ="Read More" 
      linkUrl='your url to more info on Pain Managment'
    />
       
    </div>
    
    <div class="servicesContent">
    <Cardlist 
      title="Dermatology" 
      text="The compounding pharmacist prepares therapies customized for the individual patient for a very wide range       of dermatological conditions. Such skin conditions can spell not only physical di [...]" 
      btnlink ="Read More" 
      linkUrl='your url to more info on Dermatology'
    />
    </div>

    <div class="servicesContent">
    <Cardlist
      title="Pediatric" 
      text="Children and medications often times just do not mix. Children often resist taking a medication because         they don’t like the taste. Swallowing pills is often difficult for younger children [...]" 
      btnlink ="Read More" 
      linkUrl='your url to more info on Pediatric'
    />
    </div>
    
    <div class="servicesContent">
    <Cardlist 
      title="Hormone Replacement Therapy" 
      text="Children and medications often times just do not mix. Children often resist taking a medication because         they don’t like the taste. Swallowing pills is often difficult for younger children [...]" 
      btnlink ="Read More" 
      linkUrl='your url to more info on Hormone Replacment Terapy'
    />
    </div>
</div>
</section>);
}

export default Services;
```

Comment: Yes, but for the 1st option the handleClick? Where do you pass the actual URL bro? Please excuse the question if it's dumb :) hope you can explain? also I don't need React Router for this ?

Comment: You can pass the actual URL as a prop to your CardList component, and then in handleClick you can access that prop through this.props, and use it to open it in another tab, or do anything else that you want with it. You don't need react router unless this is a SPA and the link is taking you to another part of your app.

Comment: Dude, excuse my ignorance on this? You know I want this act as a different link for each button right? If so, would you please provide 1 example of how it's done in ur code above?

Comment: I've adjusted my initial answer so you can see how to pass link url to CardList component.

Comment: Hey, one last question, if I wanted the link to link to another react page within my project, how do I do that plz ? what would I pass in the link to have go to another internal page

Comment: If you can show me how to setup the router for the button on my card component. Will learn it from here ..

Comment: Hey man , back to you again .. I really need your help on this, I need the linkUrl to open another page component under my pages folder. Is that possible at all? If not, how do I create a button link that opens up a page component?

Comment: Post another question with the problem that you are currently having and leave a link to it here, I will answer it when i get back from school if nobody else does by then.

Comment: Ok, please don’t forget man , really need ur help on this one last piece

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70828241/how-to-use-handleclick-to-link-a-react-component .. Here you go

Comment: that question has been closed

Comment: can I create a question now and  you answer there ? of there is there anyway to contact you online for 10 mins ?

Comment: i will provide you with a codepen link here

Comment: https://codepen.io/Tepsa/pen/bGYbKmG?editors=0010

Comment: I got it, but before I make fixes, please take a look at my App.js file .. I already have a router in it. Can you help me work around that one? https://codepen.io/moenagy1/pen/zYPOabP

Comment: try his https://codepen.io/Tepsa/pen/LYOPBxq?editors=0010, and please watch some react basics videos so you can understand this in the future

Comment: Your are THE MAN , I got everything working :) thanks a million bro .. helped understand a lot .. I got the router idea now .. http://www.fusionrxny.com/ that the project in progress.. Thanks again

Comment: Great, you're welcome.

Comment: You think you can assist on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70914937/how-to-edit-react-node-module-react-intense-css